# Error Create pubsubInputChannel with spring boot 2.5.5 and Spring Cloud 2.0.4

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-cloud

I was using Spring Boot 2.3.3.Release and we decided update the version to 2.5.5 and consequently spring-cloud-dependencies::2020.0.3 and spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies::2.0.4

When I run package goal in my maven my unit tests run very well. However, when I try to run Integration Tests the application fail when try to create a Pubsub Channel.
As you can see bellow.

```
2021-10-19 09:43:41.807 ERROR [,,] 1167 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pubsubInputChannel' defined in class path resource [com/xxxxx/tabesco/be/identity/verifier/configuration/SubscriberConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'integrationGlobalProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/integration/IntegrationAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties]: Factory method 'integrationGlobalProperties' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration tried to access private method 'void org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties.<init>()' (org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration and org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:123) ~[spring-boot-test-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248) ~[spring-test-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138) ~[spring-test-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:355) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$7(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:349) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:270) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:269) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:259) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:258) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:100) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:111) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:111) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:79) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71) ~[junit5-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'integrationGlobalProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/integration/IntegrationAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties]: Factory method 'integrationGlobalProperties' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration tried to access private method 'void org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties.<init>()' (org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration and org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationContextUtils.getBeanOfType(IntegrationContextUtils.java:173) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationContextUtils.getIntegrationProperties(IntegrationContextUtils.java:195) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.afterPropertiesSet(IntegrationObjectSupport.java:205) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    ... 82 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties]: Factory method 'integrationGlobalProperties' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration tried to access private method 'void org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties.<init>()' (org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration and org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    ... 96 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration tried to access private method 'void org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties.<init>()' (org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration and org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration.integrationGlobalProperties(IntegrationAutoConfiguration.java:88) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    ... 97 common frames omitted
```

Regarding the code, I haven't changed it.

'''

```
@Configuration
public class SubscriberConfiguration {

  private final Config config;
  private final OnfidoReportsCheckService oService;
  private final PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate;

  @Autowired
  public SubscriberConfiguration(Config config, OnfidoReportsCheckService oService,
      PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate) {
    this.config = config;
    this.onfidoReportsCheckService = oService;
    this.pubSubTemplate = pubSubTemplate;
  }

  @Bean
  public MessageChannel pubsubInputChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
  }

  @Bean
  public PubSubInboundChannelAdapter messageChannelAdapter(
      @Qualifier("pubsubInputChannel") MessageChannel pubsubInputChannel,
      PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate) {
    var adapter = new PubSubInboundChannelAdapter(pubSubTemplate, config.getSubscription());
    adapter.setOutputChannel(pubsubInputChannel);
    adapter.setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL);
    adapter.setPayloadType(String.class);
    return adapter;
  }

  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "pubsubInputChannel")
  public void messageReceiver(OEvent payload,
      @Header(GcpPubSubHeaders.ORIGINAL_MESSAGE) BasicAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage message) {

    try {
      log.info(String.format(LOG_RECEIVED_MSG, config.getSubscription(), payload.getDocument(),
          payload.getVideo()));



      message.ack();
    } catch (ApplicationNotFoundException | StatusRuntimeException e) {
      log.warn("Unexpected Exception: {}", e.getMessage());
      message.nack();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("Unexpected exception: {} ", e.getMessage());
      message.nack();
    }

  }

}
```

'''

'''

```
@SneakyThrows
  @Test
  void testSubscriberReceiveSuccess() {
    var status = DataGenerationUtils.STATUS_COMPLETE;
    var result = DataGenerationUtils.RESULT_CLEAR;
    var subResult = DataGenerationUtils.SUB_RESULT_CLEAR;

    var attemptEntity = DataGenerationUtils.generateVerificationAttempt(0, DocumentType.PASSPORT, "CH");
    var documentReport = DataGenerationUtils.generateOnfidoDocumentReport(status, result, subResult);
    var fReport = DataGenerationUtils
        .generateOnfidoFReport(status, result, subResult);

    OEvent.Builder builder = OEvent.newBuilder();
    builder.setCheckId(CHECK_ID);
    builder.setApplicantId(APPLICANT_ID);
    OEvent message = builder.build();


    //Publishing an event to trigger the SubscriberConfiguration
    String messageJson = JsonFormat.printer().print(message);
    publish(messageJson);


    assertTrue(true);

  }


  private void publish(String message) {

    ListenableFuture<String> future = pubSubTemplate.publish(TOPIC, message);
    future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(String result) {
        log.info("Message {} was successfully published ", message);
      }

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
        log.info("Failed to publish message {}", message);
      }
    });
  }
```

'''

Many Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 3):

```
Factory method 'integrationGlobalProperties' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration tried to access private method 'void org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationProperties.()'
```

That's means that you have not fully upgraded to Spring Boot `2.5.5`. You still have an old Spring Integration version in your dependencies somehow.

Run `mvn dependency:tree` to see how Spring Integration `5.4.x` comes to your dependencies. Or exclude it from there, or use `<spring-integration.version>5.5.4</spring-integration.version>` property to force specific version to be pulled by Spring Boot.

Comment: `at org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationContextUtils.getIntegrationProperties(IntegrationContextUtils.java:195) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]`. Sorry, not `5.4.x`, but `5.3.2`. Have no idea what can pull it for you...